# Which verb is best for "meeting" in this context?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

I want to ask a good friend for coffee. We are due for a catch-up. It is not a date or anything formal. We catch up regularly.

How do I say "I'd love to meet for coffee sometime". From looking at the basic rules, *rencontre* doesn't seem quite right, for example. Any advice gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

> On pourrait se retrouver un de ces quatre pour un café.

*Un de ces quatre* (probably an ellipsis for *un de ces quatre matins*) is a colloquial equivalent of *un de ces jours* (one of these days.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say as the comment before mine or

> On pourrai**t** se voir un de ces jours pour

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, quite informal - but which doesn't explicitly contain "to meet" (which is the specific focus of your question, I know). In defense of this version, I feel it would fit better in a casual conversation than the previous, longer proposals.

> On se prend un café un de ces quatre?

Answer (score 1):

j'aimerais qu'on prenne un café à l'occasion

ou combinaisons de :

J'aimerais

+

- qu'on se voit
- qu'on se revoit
- qu'on se rencontre

  +
- un de ces jours
- à l'occasion
- un de ces quatre (matins)

  +
- pour un café
- pour prendre/boire un café